# Spark MLLib's Word2Vec cosine similarity greater than 1

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec, neuroscience

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#word2vec

On the spark implementation of word2vec, when the number of iterations or data partitions are greater than one, for some reason, the cosine similarity is greater than 1.

In my knowledge, cosine similarity should always be about -1 < cos < 1. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4):

In `findSynonyms` method of `word2vec`, it does not calculate cosine similarity `v1・vi / |v1| |vi|`, instead it calculates `v1・vi / |vi|`, where `v1` is the vector of the query word and `vi` is the vector of the candidate words.
That's why the value sometimes exceeds 1.
Just to find closer words, it is not necessary to divide by `|v1|` because it is constant.